# Cannot convert from Parts[] to Parts

Tags: java, type-mismatch

First off, let me explain what I'm trying to do. In java, I'm creating a game that is related to one of my highschool's cca program I'm making(well handed in already) in vb6, but I'm limited to what I can do in it and so I'm working with java. The code for the class called Parts starts like this:

```
public class Parts implements Cloneable{
    public static Parts[] PartsList = new Parts[4096];
    public static HashMap<Integer,Boolean> ArrayList = new HashMap<Integer,Boolean>();
    protected boolean PartConstructerCalled = false;
    public int partTextureIndex;
    public final int partID;
    protected float partStat;
    protected String partConversion;
    private String partName;
    /**
     * To get everything started.
     */
    public static void Init_Parts(){}
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        return super.clone();
    }
    /**
    * Call this to create a new part.
    * Game crashes if an id you give is already used.
    * @param id Id to give to the part.
    */
    public Parts(int id, int textureid)
    {
        this.PartConstructerCalled = true;
        if(PartsList[id] != null){
            Variables.HackLog.severe("Part id of " + id + " is already used.");
            String partname = PartsList[id].getPartName();
            if(partname != "Un-named"){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("id " + String.valueOf(id) + " was trying to take up part id of " + id + " which is already taken up by "+PartsList[id].getPartName() + ".");
            }else{
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("id " + String.valueOf(id) + " was trying to take up part id of " + id + " which is already used.");
                }
        }else{
            this.partID = id;
            this.partName = "Un-named";
            this.partTextureIndex = textureid;
                PartsList[id] = this;
                ArrayList.put(id, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Ok that is some of the code from Parts.java, but it's the main thing to show what I need fixing. MainParts.java is where the code that I want to happen but not is(Again both code snippets ain't full code):

```
public class MainParts extends Parts{
    public static Parts[] CPU = CreatePartArray(1,1,4,"CPU");
    public static final float[] CPUStats = {1.28f,2.0f,3.36f,5.0f};
    public static final Parts Memory = new MainParts(2,2).setPartName("Memory").setPartStat(10.0f).setPartConversion("GB");
    public static final Parts Fan = new MainParts(3,3).setPartName("Fan").setPartStat(2.0f).setPartConversion("CPUs/Fan");
    public static void Init_MainParts(){
        Parts.Init_Parts();
        setPartArrayStat(CPUStats,CPU);
        setPartArrayConversion("GHz",CPU);
        Variables.HackLog.info("Parts initialized.");
    }
    public MainParts(int id, int textureid) {
        super(id, textureid);
    }
    /**
     *  This creates an array of a new part with the same id, still crashes if you create a single part or an array part with same id later on.
     *  @param id The id to give to new part
     *  @param texture The texture index to assign to part
     *  @param size The size of the array
     *  @param name To give to the array
     *  @return
     */
    public static Parts[] CreatePartArray(int id, int texture,int size,String name)
    {
        if(PartsList[id] != null){
            Variables.HackLog.severe("Part id of " + id + " is already used.");
            String partname = PartsList[id].getPartName();
            if(partname != "Un-named"){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("id " + String.valueOf(id) + " was trying to take up part id of " + id + " which is already taken up by "+PartsList[id].getPartName() + ".");
            }else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("id " + String.valueOf(id) + " was trying to take up part id of " + id + " which is already used.");
            }
        }else{
            Parts temp = new MainParts(id,texture);
            Parts[] array = new Parts[1];
            Parts[] rarray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + size);
            rarray[1] = temp;
            for(int i=2;i<rarray.length;i++){
                try{
                    rarray[i]=(MainParts)temp.clone();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            PartsList[id] = rarray[1]; //Here is what works but not what I wanted.
            ArrayList.put(id, true);
            setPartArrayName(name,rarray);
            return rarray;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I want it to look like but doesn't work:

```
public class MainParts extends Parts{
    public static Parts[] CPU = CreatePartArray(1,1,4,"CPU");
    public static final float[] CPUStats = {1.28f,2.0f,3.36f,5.0f};
    public static final Parts Memory = new MainParts(2,2).setPartName("Memory").setPartStat(10.0f).setPartConversion("GB");
    public static final Parts Fan = new MainParts(3,3).setPartName("Fan").setPartStat(2.0f).setPartConversion("CPUs/Fan");
    public static void Init_MainParts(){
        Parts.Init_Parts();
        setPartArrayStat(CPUStats,CPU);
        setPartArrayConversion("GHz",CPU);
        Variables.HackLog.info("Parts initialized.");
    }
    public MainParts(int id, int textureid) {
        super(id, textureid);
    }
    /**
     *  This creates an array of a new part with the same id, still crashes if you create a single part or an array part with same id later on.
     *  @param id The id to give to new part
     *  @param texture The texture index to assign to part
     *  @param size The size of the array
     *  @param name To give to the array
     *  @return
     */
    public static Parts[] CreatePartArray(int id, int texture,int size,String name)
    {
        if(PartsList[id] != null){
            Variables.HackLog.severe("Part id of " + id + " is already used.");
            String partname = PartsList[id].getPartName();
            if(partname != "Un-named"){
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("id " + String.valueOf(id) + " was trying to take up part id of " + id + " which is already taken up by "+PartsList[id].getPartName() + ".");
            }else{
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("id " + String.valueOf(id) + " was trying to take up part id of " + id + " which is already used.");
            }
        }else{
            Parts temp = new MainParts(id,texture);
            Parts[] array = new Parts[1];
            Parts[] rarray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + size);
            rarray[1] = temp;
            for(int i=2;i<rarray.length;i++){
                try{
                    rarray[i]=(MainParts)temp.clone();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            PartsList[id] = (Parts)rarray; //This is what I want it to look like but sadly, errors :(
            ArrayList.put(id, true);
            setPartArrayName(name,rarray);
            return rarray;
        }
    }
}
```

For the one I want it to look like gives this error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Parts[] to Parts
```

Comment: Well you've got an array, and you want a single element... so *which* element do you want, and how are you expecting the conversion to work? Why is `array` an array at all? (It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve in this code.)

Comment: Except for that code that gives an error, the 2 code fragments seem identical. What is the difference ?

Answer (score 1):

`rarray` is of type `Parts[]` which is **array of Parts objects**. You are trying to convert this to single `Parts` object. How do you thing it can be done? You can get some element from an array and assign it to some `Parts` object for example `PartsList[id] = rarray[0]`. But this is just example, I really don't have any idea what did you wanted to assign here.

Comment: Isn't his Parts[] rarray inside the if-else statement, so when it exists that statement is destroyed, so rarray[0] doesn't exist anymore anyway ? Ah my bad, havent seen the for. Nevermind :) +1

Comment: `PartsList[id] = (Parts)rarray;` is also in `else` like `Parts[] rarray = ...`

Comment: Nvm for what I want, I had to change the definition of Parts[4096] to Parts[4096][] or was it Parts[4096][4096] in the Parts.java